# Use update handler for document delete

Tags: couchdb

I need to delete a document from CouchDB, but first I need to check if a condition is met. The first thing that comes to mind is using an **update handler** instead, iterating manually over all keys in the update handler and deleting those without a `_` prefix and setting the `_delete` field to `true`.

I guess this should produce the same result as a normal `DELETE`, am I right?

**Update:**

Using @Kxepal's suggestion, this is what the update handler looks like:

```
function (doc, req) {
  if (req.query.account_id != doc.account_id) {
    return [doc, '{"error": "invalid account id"}'];
  }
  return [{
    _id: doc._id,
    _rev: doc._rev,
    _deleted: true
  }, 'ok'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.

When you `DELETE` document, CouchDB removes any fields from it except `_id` and `_rev` (sure, `_deleted` is also there). This information is also known as `tombstone`.

When you just adds `_deleted: true` to document, it becomes marked as deleted, but all other fields are still there:

`http --json http://localhost:5984/recipes/SpaghettiWithMeatballs`:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Object Not Found
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Content-Length: 41
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 17 Aug 2013 14:49:17 GMT
Server: CouchDB/1.4.0+build.c843cef (Erlang OTP/R16B)

{
    "error": "not_found", 
    "reason": "deleted"
}
```

`http --json http://localhost:5984/recipes/SpaghettiWithMeatballs\?rev\=9-ac84157c2206793b7d142f5d8e2c97d0`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Content-Length: 425
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 17 Aug 2013 14:48:55 GMT
ETag: "9-ac84157c2206793b7d142f5d8e2c97d0"
Server: CouchDB/1.4.0+build.c843cef (Erlang OTP/R16B)

{
    "_attachments": {
        "my_recipe.txt": {
            "content_type": "text/plain", 
            "digest": "md5-198BPPNiT5fqlLxoYYbjBA==", 
            "length": 85, 
            "revpos": 2, 
            "stub": true
        }
    }, 
    "_deleted": true, 
    "_id": "SpaghettiWithMeatballs", 
    "_rev": "9-ac84157c2206793b7d142f5d8e2c97d0", 
    "description": "An Italian-American dish that usually consists of spaghetti, tomato sauce and meatballs.", 
    "ingredients": [
        "spaghetti", 
        "tomato sauce", 
        "meatballs"
    ], 
    "name": "Spaghetti with meatballs"
}
```

However, during compaction, this document will be converted to `tombstone` with only `_id`, `_rev` and `_deleted` fields. Until then, this is good trick to keep data within document to easily undo delete operation without requesting document's previous revision since all content available for the latest one.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question: **"removing all non _ prefixed fields from the document"** (I do this manually in a loop inside the update handler).

Comment: As you may note, _attachments are still there, so you have to remove them too. It's better to create new object with only tombstone fields to save CPU time on deletion operation.

Comment: I guess that would be better.